# How to use array.prototype.reduce() with TypeScript while having a boolean accumulator as the initial value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, static, reduce

I was going about solving some algos on binarysearch.io and came across this problem:

[image]

I solved it using JS as follows:

```
class Solution {
    solve(nums) {
        const Hash = {};
        const Cache = {};
        
        for (let val of nums) {
            if (!Hash[val]) {
                Hash[val] = 0;
            }
            Hash[val]++; //implicit else
        }

        const result = Object.values(Hash).reduce((accum, curr) => {
            if (accum && Cache[curr] !== 'unique') {
                Cache[curr] = 'unique';
                return true
            }
            return false;
        }, true);
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, when I tried to solve it with TypeScript, which I'm fairly new to, and I had compilation errors likely caused by the .reduce() method:

```
class Solution {
    solve(nums: Array<number>): boolean {
        const Hash = {};
        const Cache = {};
        
        for (let val of nums) {
            if (!Hash[val]) {
                Hash[val] = 0;
            }
            Hash[val]++; //implicit else
        }
        
        const val_arr = Object.values(Hash);

        return val_arr.reduce((accum, curr) => {
            if (accum && Cache[curr] !== 'unique') {
                Cache[curr] = 'unique';
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, true);
    }
}
```

I'm not certain how to provide the .reduce() method a return type for the seeded initial value. I've tried changing the initial value to have a boolean type, but I still have a compilation error:

```
return val_arr.reduce((accum, curr) => {
            if (accum && Cache[curr] !== 'unique') {
                Cache[curr] = 'unique';
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, true as boolean);
```

I tried searching if anyone else has this problem, but most posts I've found have objects as the initial value, so I couldn't quite figure it out. It almost appears like the easiest solution is to solve this is to refactor to solve this without using .reduce(), but I simply want to know how to create a TS 'equivalent' to the aforementioned JS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to

(1) Type the `Hash` object properly so that the type of its keys and values can be recognized by TS

(2) Type the `Cache` object properly so that the type of its keys and values can be recognized by TS

(3) Type the accumulator as a `boolean`, rather than `true`, so that the callback inside can return either `true` or `false`. (This can be done by passing `<boolean>` as the type argument to `.reduce` - using generics is a bit preferable to `as`)

```
class Solution {
    solve(nums: Array<number>): boolean {
        const Hash: {[key: number]: number} = {};
        const Cache: {[key: number]: string} = {};
        
        for (let val of nums) {
            if (!Hash[val]) {
                Hash[val] = 0;
            }
            Hash[val]++; //implicit else
        }
        
        const val_arr = Object.values(Hash);

        return val_arr.reduce<boolean>((accum, curr) => {
            if (accum && Cache[curr] !== 'unique') {
                Cache[curr] = 'unique';
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, true);
    }
}
```

Another thing to consider - JavaScript is not Java. If you have a class that just contains a single method, with no references to instance variables, it would make much more sense structurally to define a plain function instead, eg:

```
function solve(nums: Array<number>) {
  // function implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I greatly appreciate your help!